# ListView of Textview and EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I have this layout for each element of list:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/empty_id"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_frag_empty_codice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_frag_empty_codice"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_frag_empty_codice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_frag_empty_codice"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
....
```

How can I create an adapter?
Now I get an error: "Error: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"
So I need to catch the input field of this listview, how can do it?

Comment: but is possible or I cant do it?

Comment: It is possible, its very oftenly used [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

The ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView XML exception means you don't supply what the ArrayAdapter expects. When you use this constructor:
    new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, this.file)

R.Layout.a_layout_file must be the id of a xml layout file containing only a TextView(the TextView can't be wrapped by another layout, like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc!), something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
// other attributes of the TextView
/>
```

If you want your list row layout to be something a little different then a simple TextView widget use this constructor:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, 
R.id.the_id_of_a_textview_from_the_layout, this.file)
```

where you supply the id of a layout that can contain various views, but also must contain a TextView with and id(the third parameter) that you pass to your ArrayAdapter so it can know where to put the Strings in the row layout.

Answer (score 0):

simple! You should not use ArrayAdapter with mix of components, ArrayAdapter layout should only contain TextView Widget. If you want to use other TextView then you should go for BaseAdapter.

BaseAdapter can take mix of widgets..

Answer (score 0):

```
The ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView XML exception means you don't supply what the ArrayAdapter expects. When you use this constructor:

new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, this.file)
R.Layout.a_layout_file must be the id of a xml layout file containing only a TextView(the TextView can't be wrapped by another layout, like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc!), something like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    // other attributes of the TextView
/>
If you want your list row layout to be something a little different then a simple TextView widget use this constructor:

new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, 
   R.id.the_id_of_a_textview_from_the_layout, this.file)


NOTE:In your case you have to use custom adapter.and i think you are using simple adapter.

Thanks
```